# extracting 2 Fields from each Line in a Data File and Inserting into an External Program

Tags: linux, awk

I have a data file which has 3 fields (sample data shown below, file saved as rail_only.txt):

```
10104,-31.9,115.8
12782,-31.9,115.8
12931,-31.9,115.8
13059,-32.1,116.0
```

For each line I need to extract the last two fields (which represents the latitude and longitude and use it into an input of some external script (i.e. `./calculate lat long`). I have managed to write the following script to perform the task I want, however it is very slow. I suspect there is a more efficient way using awk, however I can not make it work.

```
while read line; do

    lat_station=$(echo $line |cut -d, -f2)
    long_station=$(echo $line |cut -d, -f3)

    ./calculate $lat_station $long_station

done < rail_only.txt
```

Comment: Are you sure "very slow" comes from reading the file and not ./calculate? What happens if you comment out ./calculate? Is it still slow?

Comment: It is definitely not the calculate, I commented it out and it still ran very slowly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason your approach gets slow with more data rows is that is you call many different processes for every lat/long pair. While you read the lines, for every pair, you call 4 times `echo` and `cut`, which are programs, will take a process id, memory etc, execute and finally exit, all these are resources from the operating system. Also you call your custom program for calculation for every pair.

This is resulting to an increasing total time of execution gradually to the input, as you pay again for every line these unnecessary costs.

The standard approach to have an execution time that is increasing very slowly as the data input gets bigger, is to encapsulate all your logic in one program, where you will pay all these costs once, and you will process every line inside the same unix process, the same program.

That means you will write your read loop inside your calculation program. Your existing calculation code probably will be just inside a loop. `bash` is not ideal for classic programming, you should use a programming language you are familiar with, like `C` or `Python`, and call your program once for all the input data.

---

Now, in case you want to do this with `awk`, you could run your custom script inside only one `awk` process, something like this:

```
awk -F, 'system("./calculate " $2 " " $3)' file
```

you could see for many rows that this is probably faster than your existing approach, but still it is not efficient because we call a program for every line. You have to write your calculation in `awk` instead of calling an external script.